# Как вывести на печать страницу, сгенерированную на PHP

Tags: javascript, html, печать

Как вывести на печать страницу, сгенерированную на PHP, так, что бы при печати не было колонтитулов? А так же вопрос о размерах блока(страницы), для печати на одном листе А4 формата. Т.е. каким должен быть размер блока?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP тут не при чем, ИМХО. Единственное, что может помочь - поставить пробельный символ в тайтл, чтобы он не отображался. А вообще - это настройки браузера.
Про блок не понял. 
Стандарт - 2к символов на лист А4. Это очень приближенно и очень условно. 
Чаще всего, страница на листе А4 получается более узкой, чем на экране. Почему - не знаю.
Последняя рекомендация - использовать CSS Media:

```
@media print {
  /* Тут стандартные свойства CSS для отображения на печати. */
}
```

Соответственно, минимум картинок, максимум контраста и максимум резиновости.

Comment: >Про блок не понял
Ну я имею в виду, чтоб сделать допустим один <div> фиксированных размеров и его уже набивать контентом. Вот и вопрос откуда возник, каким он должен быть, в смысле размеров. Просто в инете еще нарыл такую информацию, что через css размеры надо задавать либо в дюймах, либо в сантиметрах, а в пикселях нельзя.

А про заголовки, так то понятно, что их можно отключить перед печатью, но в настройках браузера. А хотелось бы как-то скриптом или, допустим, передать на печать пустые колонтитулы

Comment: >либо в дюймах, либо в сантиметрах, а в пикселях нельзя.  

Что за сайт? очень интересно что авторы скажут про конструкцию, типа:

    h1{
      line-height: 1em;
      margin: 10px 10% 0 10%;
      padding: 2px;
    }  

Управлять колонтитулами нельзя. Скажем так, всегда можно сделать так, чтобы они все-таки напечатались. По-умолчанию печатается адрес и номер страницы.

По поводу блоков
    
    page-break-before: auto/always/avoid/left/right/inherit;  

Может, поможет?

Comment: Про дюймы или сантиметры, вот откуда взял http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/personal/18580/
Ладно, спасибо, буду пробовать!